# Extract currency from formatted amount

Tags: java, parsing, currency

I'm getting a formatted amount of money from a web service. It can be in different formats and using different currencies, e.g.

- `$ 1.10`
- `€ 1,10`
- `1,10 €`
- `EUR 1.10` (perhaps, I'm not sure I'll actually encounter this one)

I would like to extract the currency symbol (`$`) from it, and if possible get the associated `Currency` object (Java) from that symbol. I don't need to extract the amount, I can get that somewhere else.

Comment: The accepted SO answer here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116507/arbitrary-currency-string-get-all-parts-separated

Answer (score 4):

you can use a regular expression, to parse your result from the webservice. You have to filter all characters, except numbers, dots and whitespaces. Here is the regex for that:

```
String regexp = "[^0-9\\.,\\s]*";
```

The first group of the matching result is the currency symbol (or the name e.g. EUR).

Here is my sample method:

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    String text = "2.02 $";
    String regexp = "[^0-9\\.,\\s]*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount() + 1; i++)
            LOG.info(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `throws Exception` (instead of `try/catch/System.out.printStackTrace`)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Joda Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/), it might offer a solution for your problem. Caution: it is still version 0.6

Answer (score 0):

`getSymbol()` method from `java.util.Currency` will help you to get the currency symbol